# How to send automatic emails on click event from UWP/Windows Store app (2019) without using email interface but using Yahoo SMTP

Tags: c#, email, uwp

Trying to send an automatic email from UWP/Windows Store (2019) app using yahoo smtp and without email interface popping up on click event.

- Does anyone have the code for this?  I will be using static from and to email addresses.
- This needs to work regardless of where the app is installed, i.e. multiple PCs.

I have tried **LightBuzz** NuGet Package using this and it still does not send any emails nor does the app crash or gives errors:

```
using LightBuzz.SMTP;

// The below call to SendMailAsync is used in a click event
SendMailAsync();
// 

public async static void SendMailAsync()
        {
            var server = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
            var port = 587;
            var ssl = true;
            var username = "myemail@yahoo.com";
            var password = "myPassword"; 

            using (var client = new SmtpClient(server, port, ssl, username, password))
            {
                var emailMessage = new EmailMessage();

                emailMessage.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("myemail@yahoo.com"));
                emailMessage.CC.Add(new EmailRecipient(""));
                emailMessage.Bcc.Add(new EmailRecipient(""));

                emailMessage.Subject = "My Subject";
                emailMessage.Body = "My Msg.";

                await client.SendMailAsync(emailMessage);
            }
        }
```

I expect the email to arrive in my yahoo mailbox. But nothing ever comes.

Comment: **Pro tip:**  Try to minimize the amount of 3rd party NuGet packages you use in a Windows Store app.  Just because something is marked as UWP-compatible doesn't mean it will pass certification by the _Windows App Certification Kit_.   I learnt this the hard way with `log4net` and the native calls it is making

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: Where is "From" address?

Comment: @ i486 I have removed the above code from my app.  Since my App is already published in the MS Store I don't want to add this and then not get it published again or removed from the store.    To be honest all I want to do is send myself an automatic email from my app if someone clicks a link to request support so that they don't have to waste time doing it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the general `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` class, it's not supported in UWP. See [.NET API Browser for SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0&term=System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient).

But I found some useful information on the **Important** section of the [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) document.

The [dotnet/platform-compat](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md) on github suggests you to use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). It's an open source library. It supports .NET 4.5, .NETStandard 1.3/1.6/2.0, Windows Universal 8.1, Xamarin.Android, and Xamarin.iOS.

So, you could use it in UWP. I've install the nuget package to test the [demo code](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit#sending-messages). It works in UWP. You could try it.

Comment: Thanks Xavier.  I will try it and let you know if it works for me as well.

Comment: @DharkUndercity Can't you send email successfully by using this library APIs?